# Python 3 scrape html data

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, scrape

I plan to extract data fromthe following website html
link:http://movie.walkerplus.com/list/2015/12/

some part of html is shown as following:

```
<dl class="directorList">
<dt>監督</dt>
<dd>
<a href="/person/209306/" title="">スティーヴ・マーティノ</a>
</dd>
</dl>
<dl class="roleList">
<dt>出演キャスト</dt>
<dd>
<a href="/person/226530/" title="">鈴木福</a>
<a href="/person/228506/" title="">芦田愛菜</a>
<a href="/person/266939/" title="">小林星蘭</a>
</dd>
```

I want to get all the directionList data and 出演キャス in this site

such as   スティーヴ・マーティノ, 
          鈴木福 芦田愛菜 小林星蘭

my code is shown as following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

html = urlopen("http://movie.walkerplus.com/list/2015/12/")
bsObj_movie = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
print(bsObj_movie)
movie_title = bsObj_movie.findAll({"h3"})
movie_description = bsObj_movie.findAll("p", {"class": "clearboth"})
movie_directors = bsObj_movie.findAll("dl", {"class": "directorList"})
movie_roles = bsObj_movie.findAll("dl", {"class": "roleList"})
for description in movie_description:
  print(description.get_text())
for title in movie_title:
  print(title.get_text())
for director in movie_directors:
 print(director.find('a').get_text())
for role in movie_roles:
  print(role.get_text())
```

I have got successfully the movie_title and movie_description,
but the movie_directors and movie_roles is shown as following.

監督

セルゲイ・ボドロフ

出演キャスト

鈴木福
芦田愛菜
小林星蘭

Actually, I just want to extract the following data, not include:監督 and 出演キャスト.And  I want to print the title, description, director and role, not just director and role. Further, I want to extract these datas and store it to a database which has a table include four columns:  title, description, director and role.

セルゲイ・ボドロフ

鈴木福
芦田愛菜
小林星蘭

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Not every *movie* i.e `The Royal Opera House Cinema Season 2015/16 Royal Opera "The Marriage of Figaro"` on the first page  has a director so I filtered those out:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

html = urlopen("http://movie.walkerplus.com/list/2015/12/")
soup  = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

data = soup.select("div.movie dl.directorList")

for  d in data:
    title = d.select_one("a").text
    description = d.find_previous("p", "clearboth").text
    cast = ",".join([a.text.strip() for a in d.find_next("dl","roleList").select("dd a")])
    director = d.dd.a.text
    print(title, director, cast, description)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to print the title, description, director and role, not just director and role. I want to extract these datas and store it to a data base which has a table include four columns:  title, description, director and role.